# Round CountDown timer? (millispersecond accuracy)?

Tags: java, android, math, timer, clock

I am using countDownTimer in my code. The problem is, countdowntimer is not accurate. The onTick method will not always execute every second, it can be a few milliseconds off. This becomes an issue when trying to execute a certain task based on millisUntilFinished. I am trying to log when ten seconds of my 20 second timer has passed:

Here is the relevant code:

```
    if (millisUntilFinished == 10000) { //TEN SECONDS

                Log.v(TAG, "TEN SECONDS LEFT");
            }
```

The issue arises here, as countDownTimer may never even **have** millisUntilFinished == 10000, it may equal 1001 and so my code will not execute. Is there anyway to somehow round the millisUntilFinished (which is a long) to the nearest thousands? I have tried the following:

```
 millisUntilFinishedRounded = MathUtils.round((double) millisUntilFinished, -3); // nearest thousand, 2000.0
```

but I cannot resolve 'MathUtils'

I am lost. I would really appreciate any feedback (positive or negative)! Thank you so much for all of your help.

```
{Rich}
```

Comment: `((500 + millisUntilFinished) / 1000) * 1000` rounds a positive value to the nearest 1000. But you could use `(millisUntilFinished >= 9500 && millisUntilFinished < 10500)` as your condition alternatively.

Comment: Or if you want to execute some code one time. Just check if millisUntilFinished < 10000 and then a set a boolean to say the code was executed so it doesn't run next time.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for your time, why are we adding 500?

Comment: You need to add 500 if you want to round to the nearest 1000, as opposed to rounding *down* to the nearest 1000. e.g. for 750: `(750 + 500) / 1000 * 1000 = 1000`, whereas `750 / 1000 * 1000 = 0`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Your answer is working! I am a little bit confused why though... Isn't 900/1000 = 0.9? 0.9 x 1000 = 9000, not 10000; why does this still work though? Is it rounding up from 0.9 -> 1? If so, how would it work if the quotient was above one but below 2, would it still round up again, to two? thanks so much for the answer, I will mark it as best answer and like your post as soon as these questions are answered! :)

Comment: @AndyTurner Isn't 750 / 1000 * 1000 = 750 and (750 + 500) / 1000 * 1000 = 900? Why does it work then?

Comment: @Rich not in integer arithmetic: `750 / 1000 = 0`; `(750 + 500) / 1000 = 1250 / 1000 = 1`. (No idea where you get 900 from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few alternatives:

1. You can round a positive integer to the nearest N by adding N/2, dividing by N and multiplying by N again:

   ((500 + millisUntilFinished) / 1000) * 1000
2. You can use a condition which just checks if the value is in the range which would be rounded to 10000:

   millisUntilFinished >= 9500 && millisUntilFinished < 10500
3. You can check for the first time that `millisUntilFinished` drops below 10000:

   ```
   boolean printedMessage = false;
   while (true) {
     millisUntilFinished = ...
     if (!printedMessage && millisUntilFinished < 10000) {
       System.out.println("Your message");
       printedMessage = true;
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Oh, I understand! Thanks so much. I liked and marked best answer!

Comment: I guess java always rounds down, so to prevent getting 10 twice, add 500. Very clever!

Comment: Java rounds *towards zero*, i.e. it rounds up for negative numbers. That's why I stipulated the method is for a positive integer. (Actually, non-negative would be more precise).